# Google Sites custom path character limit?

Tags: google-sites

I'm trying to add a page to my Google site which links to a Google sheet.

I get the URL from the sheet, but when I insert that as a custom path, the address is truncated, and I get the message "invalid path".

This used to work, as I have several pages which reference an individual sheet. But it appears to me that Google has implemented a character limit for URL addresses. I tried to get around this by creating a Tinyurl, but Google still rejects it.

How do I add a page to my Google site with a custom path?

Thanks,
Fred

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to insert a Google Sheet into a Google Site, there is a ['Drive' Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lg05B.png) which allows you to insert a Google file.

If you want to insert a custom url, you can try other link shorteners, like bit.ly

> I tried to get around this by creating a Tinyurl, but Google still rejects it.

Google may block 'Tinyurl', but there must be other supported link shortening websites, so my advice is to try a few.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can't use the Drive button, as it doesn't insert the parameters that I need (&widget=false, etc.). The problem I have is no matter what URL I enter in the Custom Path box (even "www.google.com") I get the message "Invalid Path".

Comment: Hi. This is probably a bug with Google Sites and it would be worth reporting this to their team. Just to check: you aren't using the legacy version? @FredSmith

Comment: Thanks, Taylor. I have reported it to Google, but no response (yet). I expect it will be fixed eventually.

Comment: Good, I hope this is resolved for you soon... :)